# WORD 2003 - Adding Hyperlinks to other files....can I use currentpath in the hyperlink

Tags: vba, hyperlink, ms-word

I have a document that is an overview document within a folder, there are numerous related documents in a folder that is also in the folder that contains the overview document.

I would like to reference these documents throughout the overview document and allow those to be selected and viewed by clicking.

so i was going to use a hyperlink....but if this folder gets distributed then the hyperlink URL is instantly no good.

So in access I could use a MyPath = currentpath & "\SubFolder.... " idea.

Can I use the same kind of idea here with a hyperlink? How?

I don't seem to be able to add buttons to word documents like with Access and Excel?

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the hyperlink relative to the document, this way when it's distributes, the references are kept.